# Ganache Error/Bug?: Incompatible EIP155-based V 0 and chain id 1

Tags: ganache, blockchain-fork

I'm trying to mainnet-fork using the Ganache UI (instead of ganache-cli which seems to work fine.)

The error mentions the chain id. I've used all sorts of chain ids. Mostly 1377 and 1.
I'm not really sure what a "chain id" actually is but I'm not convinced it's the source of the bomb.

What am I doing wrong? Surely Ganache isn't this buggy?

```
fork=https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/L6gxq3hs4F2tCVN2hA0PbwK-FSAyEMGz
```

[image: Here are the main settings I use:]

> Error: Incompatible EIP155-based V 0 and chain id 1. See the second parameter of the Transaction constructor to set the chain id.
> at Transaction._validateV (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\static\node\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-tx\src\transaction.ts:370:13)
> at Transaction.set [as v] (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\static\node\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-tx\src\transaction.ts:387:16)
> at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\static\node\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\transaction.js:116:23
> at Array.forEach ()
> at initData (C:\Program ............
> ............................

de\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:179:9)
at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\app\resources\static\node\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\forking\forked_blockchain.js:136:11
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

[image: Ganache error/bug??]